# Passing an anonymous method into ProgressBar.Invoke()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, invoke

I am trying to pass in a delegate using an anonymous method into `progressBar.Invoke(Delegate)`:

```
progressBar.Invoke(() => progressBar.Value = count);
```

But I get the following error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type.

Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That method takes a Delegate, not an Action. Therefore, when you do just this:

```
() => { .. }
```

It doesn't know what delegate you want. Do this instead:

```
progressBar.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Value = count));
```

Answer (score 3):

`Invoke` doesn't take a particular type of delegate, it takes a `Delegate` (meaning it can take any delegate with any signature).  You need to pass in a specific type of delegate (it doesn't matter which one you choose):

```
progressBar.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Value = count));
```